# Streaming from USB plugged into router to LG Smart TV

Tags: router, usb, streaming, video-streaming, lg-monitor

I have an LG 55LA620S-ZA Smart TV and I here is what I am trying to do: I want to see the content of my USB flash drive which is plugged into my home router a D-Link DSL-2750B by using my WI-FI internet connection. However when I get to the LG Smart Share section, I have no trace of the files contained in the USB.

What should I do in order to stream the content of the USB directly to my LG TV without having to channel the data through a PC or a Smartphone?

Comment: Are you making a Wi-Fi Direct connection to the router, or are you trying to read from the TV's USB?

Comment: Hello @RonMaupin, I am trying to do a Wi-Fi Direct connection to the router.

Comment: Did you enable Wi-Fi Direct on the router, or does the router even support that?

Comment: I am not quite sure about that; let me check and I'll comment back asap

Comment: I cannot find Wi-Fi Direct on the router options; I see it however on my Smart Tv but I cannot select it.

Comment: According to the LG manual, you must have Wi-Fi Direct enabled on the device from which you wish to get content. If your router doesn't support Wi-Fi Direct, I think you are out of luck.

Comment: Ok thank you very much... I believe I won't be able to achieve my goal... thanks anyways